# Ruby JBuilder with variable names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, jbuilder

How do I use a variable name when constructing a JSON using `jBuilder` in Ruby?

For example, suppose I have a variable `var1`:

```
var1 = "query_string"
query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
          json.query do
            json.query_string do
              json.query "SOMETHING"
            end
          end
        end
```

How can I do something like:

```
json.var1 do
```

Rather than explicitly: `json.query_string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send a message whose name is not statically known, you can use the [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method:

```
var1 = 'query_string'

query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.query do
    json.public_send(var1) do
      json.query "SOMETHING"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can alternatively use `set!` method.

jbuider's docs on github gives this example:

```
json.set! :author do
  json.set! :name, 'David'
end

# => {"author": { "name": "David" }}
```

For your example, it would be something like:

```
var1 = "query_string"
query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.query do
    json.set! var1 do
      json.query "SOMETHING"
    end
  end
end
```